# Inlineshape select method in C#

Tags: c#

I have been trying the following code in C# to extract image but i'm getting as shown below:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

 oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(ref str1......);

oDoc.InlineShapes.Select();
```

Error:

```
oDoc.InlineShapes.Select();
The requested member of the collection does not exist.
```

Please let me know what can be wrong with this line?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell the `InlineShapes` collection does not have a naked `Select()` method. Therefore I am assuming that you are trying to use linq on the collection.

[`InlineShapes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is an implementation of [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) which does not have a `Select(...)` method.

I suspect that you need to do this,

```
// Note the select is spurious here
oDoc.InlineShapes.OfType<InlineShape>().Select((shape) => shape)
```

`OfType<T>()` returns an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) which does support the `Select(...)` method.

Consider that if `IEnumerable` was extended by `Select(...)` there wouldn't be any useful properties on the `Object` type for you to use.

**EDIT**

If you want to get the images from the InlineShapes you could...

```
 var pictures = oDoc.InlineShapes.OfType<InlineShape>().Where(s =>
    s.Type = WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture ||
    s.Type = WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture ||
    s.Type = WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePictureHorizontalLine ||
    s.Type = WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapeLinkedPictureHorizontalLine);

 foreach(var picture in pictures)
 {
     picture.Select();
     oWord.Selection.Copy()

     //Then you need to retrieve the contents of the clipboard
     //which I feel is another question.
 }
```

That should give you a set of all the inline shapes in the document that have a picture.

Comment: Your logic does not select the image in doc file.

Comment: try that, I haven't compiled this code myself, just written it to hopefully guide you in the right direction.

Comment: which version of .net are you using and what errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and it gives red line under " WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture"